# Arraylist not adding data and when called redirects me to another page

Tags: java, list, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

Creating a supermarket software and when I go to add products page, if the category and brand is not added yet, then the page redirects to category add and 
brands add page.

There is the data already in the table and yet the page redirects to the add category page.

UserDAO for Category

```
    PreparedStatement ps =null;
    String query = "SELECT CategoryId, CategoryName from tbl_category";

    List <CategoryModel> categories = new ArrayList<CategoryModel>();
    CategoryModel categoryModel = new CategoryModel();

    CategoryModel u = null;
    try{
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, categoryModel.getCategoryId());
        ps.setString(2, categoryModel.getCategoryName());

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            u.setCategoryId(rs.getString("CategoryId"));
            u.setCategoryName(rs.getString("CategoryName"));
            categories.add(u);
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return categories;
}
```

UserDAO for brand

```
    PreparedStatement ps =null;
    String query = "SELECT BrandId, BrandName from tbl_brand";

    List <BrandModel> brands = new ArrayList<BrandModel>();
    BrandModel brandModel = new BrandModel();

    BrandModel u = null;    
    try{
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, brandModel.getBrandId());
        ps.setString(2, brandModel.getBrandName());

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){

            u.setBrandId(rs.getString("BrandId"));
            u.setBrandName(rs.getString("BrandName"));
            brands.add(u);

        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return brands;
}
```

Servlet for retrieving data and redirect

```
     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse        response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    session = request.getSession();
    List<BrandModel> brands=null;
    List<CategoryModel> categories=null;

    UserDAOImplementation brand = new UserDAOImplementation();

    brands = brand.brands();

    UserDAOImplementation category = new UserDAOImplementation();

    List<CategoryModel> catagories = category.catagories();


    if(category==null){
        response.sendRedirect("views/products/Category.jsp");
    }else if(brands==null){
        response.sendRedirect("views/products/Brands.jsp");
    }else if(categories.isEmpty()){
        response.sendRedirect("views/products/Category.jsp");
    }else if(brands.isEmpty()){
        response.sendRedirect("views/products/Brands.jsp");
    }else{
    session.setAttribute("brands", brand);
    session.setAttribute("categories", category);
    response.sendRedirect("views/products/Product.jsp");

    }


}
```

Comment: as a side note, you are only working with once instance of `BrandModel` and `CategoryModel`, which you keep modifing. I´d create new instances of it in the loop, otherwise you'll end up with X times the same instance of each in the `List` where X is the amount of items in the table.

Comment: Your code has null pointer problems. In multiple places you initialise a variable as `null` and then try and assign to its fields. Assuming you get any results at all, you'll just get NullPointerExceptions every time.

Comment: Are you sure that it's an `ArrayList` who redirects you? If yes, it's pretty strange...

Comment: Your code is not complete. Where are `brands` or `categories` methods? in dao of Category `categoryModel.getCategoryId()` don't has any value? please test your code and complete your question

Comment: I just read the first snippet, and it makes no sense: the query has no parameter, yet you bind two parameters. These parameters always have the same value. You're always adding the same instance of CategoryModel to the list. And of course, you don't properly close the resultset and the statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
PreparedStatement ps =null; String query = "SELECT CategoryId, CategoryName from tbl_category";

List <CategoryModel> categories = new ArrayList<CategoryModel>(); CategoryModel categoryModel = new CategoryModel();

CategoryModel u = null; try{
    ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, categoryModel.getCategoryId());
    ps.setString(2, categoryModel.getCategoryName());

    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

and

```
PreparedStatement ps =null; String query = "SELECT BrandId, BrandName from tbl_brand";

    List <BrandModel> brands = new ArrayList<BrandModel>();
    BrandModel brandModel = new BrandModel();

    BrandModel u = null;    
    try{
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, brandModel.getBrandId());
        ps.setString(2, brandModel.getBrandName());
```

In both cases you are setting input parameters for a query without having any placeholders for input parameters (`?`). As such, I assume trying to call setString throws an exception, which you catch and return the output as null, which then causes the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

```
        BrandModel u = null;    
        try{
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();


        while(rs.next()){
            u = new BrandModel();
            u.setBrandId(rs.getString("BrandId"));
            u.setBrandName(rs.getString("BrandName"));
            brands.add(u);
            System.out.println(u.getBrandId());
            System.out.println(u.getBrandName());

        }
```

// For Category

```
         List <CategoryModel> categories = new ArrayList<CategoryModel>();
         CategoryModel categoryModel = new CategoryModel();

         CategoryModel u = null;
         try{
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            u =  new CategoryModel();
            u.setCategoryId(rs.getString("CategoryId"));
            u.setCategoryName(rs.getString("CategoryName"));
            categories.add(u);
            System.out.println(u.getCategoryId());
            System.out.println(u.getCategoryName());

        }
```